# Page Not Refreshing After submitting a form to update MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql, caching, meta-tags

When i update Mysql table using a form over php page, the page does not automaticly refreshes when i hit submit. I have to hit refresh to see the updated rows.
i tried but this did not work either any good ideas?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

///////////////////////Edited Bottom////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<?php

include ("../header.php");
include ("../header2.php");

?>
<?php
include('../config.php');
include ('../ac.thumbs.php');

 if ($_GET['sil']) {
    $sil = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET['sil']));
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM CloseOut WHERE itemNO = $sil limit 1");
    echo "<h1>$sil item nolu kayit silinmistir</h1><br>";
}

    $edit = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET['edit']));
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CloseOut WHERE itemNO=$edit") or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { echo "
<center>
<a href=\"edit.php?sil=$info[itemNO]\"onclick=\"return confirm('Do you really want to erase this entry?')\">[ Delete ]</a><br>
<a href=../../large.php?f=upload/".$info['resim'], $thumblarge .">
<img src=../../small.php?f=upload/".$info['resim'], $thumbsmall .">
</a>";
$editresim = $info[resim];
$editisim = $info[isim];
$editalan1 = $info[alan1];
$editalan2 = $info[alan2];
$editalan3 = $info[alan3];
$editalan4 = $info[alan4];
} 

 //Resimlerin yuklenecegin yer
 $target = "../../upload/";  
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ///////////////////////////////Resim1/////////////////////////////////
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 $target1 = $target . basename( $_FILES['resim1']['name']) ; 
 //Formdan gelen bilgileri almasi icin
 $resim=($_FILES['resim1']['name']); 
 $isim=$_POST['isim1']; 
 $alan1=$_POST['alan11']; 
 $alan2=$_POST['alan21']; 
 $alan3=$_POST['alan31']; 
 $alan4=$_POST['alan41']; 



/////////////Formdaki bos alanlara bos bilgi kayit etmemesi icin////////////////////////

$updates = array();
if (!empty($resim))
  $updates[] = 'resim="'.mysql_real_escape_string($resim).'"';
if (!empty($isim))
  $updates[] = 'isim="'.mysql_real_escape_string($isim).'"';
if (!empty($alan1))
  $updates[] = 'alan1="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan1).'"';
if (!empty($alan2))
  $updates[] = 'alan2="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan2).'"';
if (!empty($alan3))
  $updates[] = 'alan3="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan3).'"';
if (!empty($alan4))
  $updates[] = 'alan4="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan4).'"';
$updates = implode(', ', $updates);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //update etmesi icin
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resim1']['tmp_name'], $target1)) 
{   
mysql_query("UPDATE CloseOut SET $updates WHERE itemNO='$edit' ");
echo "Tebrikler, ". basename( $_FILES['resim1']['name']). " isimli dosya yuklendi ve database'e basariyla islendi!<br>"; 
 } 




?>

<br>
<center> 
<table width="900" border="5" style="background-color:white; "bordercolor="#000000">
    <tr>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>RESIM</b></td>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>NAME</b></td>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>CATAGORY</b></td>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>QUANTITY</b></td>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>LOCATION</b></td>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>PRICE</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<td><input type="file" name="resim1" value="<?php echo $editresim;?>"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="isim1" value="<?php echo $editisim;?>"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="alan11" value="<?php echo $editalan1;?>"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="alan21" value="<?php echo $editalan2;?>">  </td>
<td><input type="text" name="alan31" value="<?php echo $editalan3;?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="alan41" value="<?php echo $editalan4;?>"></td>
</tr>

<td colspan="6"><center><input type="submit"></center></td>


</form>
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your form.

Comment: Can you paste your code with form structure?

Comment: Yup. Can we see the form?

Comment: are you redirecting after update on the same page?

Comment: Check your POST in form. you might have missed to give the name of script in this.

Comment: Please show the form processor code, maybe they're placed *after* the code for displaying the result. And using caps in HTML like that is old.

Comment: I edited the question thank you for your attention everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you see it now? `$editresim` value is `$info[resim]`.

When you submit the form, `$info[resim]` is the **current** database value. Database got updated below/after that.

When you Submit, you'll still see the previous data before the submitted value are actually placed into database. And thus you need to reopen that page to see the updated data.

One way to fix it, you should move the code to update data to top, before you `SELECT * FROM CloseOut WHERE itemNO=$edit`, so that query will give you the latest/updated data.

Sorry for not providing sample codes, but I'm afraid I'll make some tiny errors which could add to the confusion. And it's actually better if you try to solve it yourself.

Good luck!

ps: Your logic

```
Get data from db

Put to data to VAR

If form is submitted:

    Update data in DB

Show VAR // This is *not* the latest submitted data
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer +1 but i dont have enough rep

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are updating the database **AFTER** you get the information.

put this part of the code

```
//Resimlerin yuklenecegin yer
 $target = "../../upload/";  
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ///////////////////////////////Resim1/////////////////////////////////
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 $target1 = $target . basename( $_FILES['resim1']['name']) ; 
 //Formdan gelen bilgileri almasi icin
 $resim=($_FILES['resim1']['name']); 
 $isim=$_POST['isim1']; 
 $alan1=$_POST['alan11']; 
 $alan2=$_POST['alan21']; 
 $alan3=$_POST['alan31']; 
 $alan4=$_POST['alan41']; 



/////////////Formdaki bos alanlara bos bilgi kayit etmemesi icin////////////////////////

$updates = array();
if (!empty($resim))
  $updates[] = 'resim="'.mysql_real_escape_string($resim).'"';
if (!empty($isim))
  $updates[] = 'isim="'.mysql_real_escape_string($isim).'"';
if (!empty($alan1))
  $updates[] = 'alan1="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan1).'"';
if (!empty($alan2))
  $updates[] = 'alan2="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan2).'"';
if (!empty($alan3))
  $updates[] = 'alan3="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan3).'"';
if (!empty($alan4))
  $updates[] = 'alan4="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan4).'"';
$updates = implode(', ', $updates);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //update etmesi icin
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resim1']['tmp_name'], $target1)) 
{   
mysql_query("UPDATE CloseOut SET $updates WHERE itemNO='$edit' ");
echo "Tebrikler, ". basename( $_FILES['resim1']['name']). " isimli dosya yuklendi ve database'e basariyla islendi!<br>"; 
 }
```

**just before:**

```
$edit = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET['edit']));
```